# Springboot does not assign value to OffsetDateTime field

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have a model with OffsetDateTime field in it:

```
public class Todo {
    @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
    @JsonProperty("creationTime")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    OffsetDateTime creationTime;

    @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
    @JsonProperty("title")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    String title;

}
```

Springboot always assigns a null value to creationTime field. If I don't provide datetime in ISO861 format, I do get parsing exception.

However, after implementing a @JsonComponent class, I can see the value being assigned.

```
@JsonComponent
public class OffsetDateSerializer {
    public static class OffSetDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<OffsetDateTime> {

        @Override
        public OffsetDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Some");
            TreeNode treeNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);

            TextNode textNode = (TextNode) treeNode;
            return OffsetDateTime.parse(textNode.asText());
        }
    }
}
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure OffsetDateSerializer's path for component scanning. JsonComponentModule(org.springframework.boot.jackson) registers json beans which annotated with @JsonComponent.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("your OffsetDateSerializer's path")
public class SerializerConfig {

}
```